# How to center a responsive box on the same row as a left aligned box?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I currently have a NavBar with a logo and a search bar as depicted below:

[image]

and I would like to center the search bar on larger screens and have the search bar consume the empty space on the navbar without overflowing onto the logo on the left. Here is the code for the NavBar:

```
  const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <Flex>
      <Center p="3">
        <Link href="/">
          <a>MarketBuddy</a>
        </Link>
      </Center>
      <Box p="4" flex="1" maxW="500">
        <SearchBar />
      </Box>
    </Flex>
  );
};
```

Any pointers on how to do so would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give the search bar `flex-grow: 1`?

Comment: The issue is that the search bar is not centered in it's container. The width of the search bar is how I'd like it, however, it is not centered.

Comment: In that case perhaps giving the search bar `justify-self: center` may work, assuming the parent container has `flex-direction: row`

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is by adding another instance of the logo as a third child of the navbar (on the right) but with `visibility: hidden;`. It will create an empty space of the size of the logo, and then `flex-grow: 1;` or similar on the search bar should do what you want. Not sure how to do it with pure CSS otherwise.